# Is a Potion of Acquiescence consumed if it fails in werewolv.es?

Tags: werewolv.es

Is a potion of acquiescence on [werewolv.es](https://werewolv.es/) still used up if it's used on thief's target same night, which would mean no thefts take place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A consumable item is used up whether or not the result is "successful", for example a crossbow is still used up even if it hits a player with armour.

So if the potion bounces because a Thief targets the the same player, or another player uses a separate potion of acquiescence, the potion(s) are still used up.